# Enerprise SuSE, GRUB startup "error 2"

Tags: grub, suse

A few hours ago I just bought a new HP Probook 4540s which has an Enterprise SuSE 12 built-in installed on that. I'm just trying to turn-it on and there is an error `GRUB ERROR 2 ...`, and nothing else. The guy on the shop just tweaked a few things on the BIOS to show me the HDD capacity, however I just reset everything in BIOS to the default.

Does anyone knows what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Grub error 2 means "Bad File or Directory Type", the grub.conf is not set up properly. You may need to reinstall the Distro. You can also look at this site and see if it is of any help.

http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/installation/127502-grub-error-2-a.html

Anyway, something is clearly wrong with the boot loader. I can't help any more than that though.

Comment: thanks man, I had found the same info on the 'net ... let see if any other one could help ... thanks by the way! :)